# Can one data table get values from another data table

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where I'm attempting to gather data through two tiers of calculation.  I have a range of 20 numbers that I need to lookup and calculate some complex formulas, so I created a data table (Call it B) to do this.  It seems to work properly.

But, I actually have a list of 30 different lists of 20 numbers that I need to analyze, so I created a second data table (Call it A) that uses the results of the first data table.

Again, it appears to work, but it is not calculating properly.

If I updated the input cell for Data Table A to any individual value from the table, it calculates properly, though I have to manually update the value.  BUT, each time I change that input value, all the other output values change, and calculate incorrectly.

So, is this a but in Excel, is it possible to have one data table that references another data table?